# terraform plan does not detect drift

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, infrastructure-as-code

I had a very basic configuration of ec2 containing only

AMI and instance type:

```
provider "aws" {
  region="ap-south-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "tec3"{
    ami=var.image_id
    instance_type=var.instance_type
    subnet_id=var.default_subnet
}
```

But I noticed a strange behavior of the terraform plan and tfstate file.

1st Scenario:

When I added a new tag in the console(**which is not present in the desired configuration/state**), it is shown as a change to be deleted upon doing terraform plan.

2nd Scenario:

When I changed the credit specification to unlimited from console(**which is also not present in the desired configuration/state**). Architecture is shown as up-to-date upon terraform plan.

Can you please tell me, why this happened?

According to my understanding, attributes that are not present in the desired configuration don't get affected by the changes made in the console.

So infrastructure should have been shown up-to-date in both of the scenarios.

Please explain this and any other scenarios as well to keep in mind for the future. while changing from the console.

Comment: I see what you mean. Could be bug. Similar issues have been reported as bugs and resolved. An example [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7160).

Answer (score 0):

The capability for detecting drift depends on various design details of each individual provider, and often provider teams are working within other constraints or have other priorities that they prioritize over drift detection. For that reason, Terraform provider drift detection is a *best effort* feature and not something you should build your processes to rely on.

While I'm not familiar with the specific provider features you're describing here, one reason why a provider might be implemented to ignore drift in certain cases is if the value of an unset argument is chosen dynamically by the server rather than set explicitly in your configuration or in the provider itself. In that case, the provider's only record of the value is the value in the remote system and thus there's nothing to compare that value with in order to detect drift.

You can give providers a better opportunity to detect drift by explicitly setting a value for each of your arguments in the configuration, rather than leaving the remote system to choose a default value:

```
resource "aws_instance" "tec3"{
  ami           = var.image_id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  subnet_id     = var.default_subnet

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
}
```

Although it's still ultimately up to the provider implementation to decide what counts as drift and what doesn't, writing an explicit argument in the configuration will at least give the provider a *desired value* to compare the remote system to, and thus allow it to potentially detect and plan to correct unwanted changes to that particular argument.

---

**Update:** In the AWS provider repository's [issue #17856](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17856) a member of the AWS provider team independently confirmed my assumption that this was an intentional design decision on the part of the team but includes some different and more detailed rationale for why that is so, for this particular case and also generally about some tradeoffs the AWS provider team makes when evolving existing resource types to support new AWS API behaviors.

Comment: Hello Martin,
Both the tags and credit specification are not mentioned in my configuration.
But the terraform is able to detect drift for tags but not credit specification.
Can it be a bug or there is some logic behind that.

Comment: `tags` is an example of an argument that is only ever chosen by you in your configuration, and never populated automatically by the remote API, and so unlike with `cpu_credits` I expect the AWS provider is treating your absent `tags` the same as `tags = {}`, and can therefore detect drift in that case. But like I said, the behavior is different for each attribute depending on how the provider is implemented (and might change between releases), so you should never rely on drift detection as part of your main workflow.

Comment: got it martin :),
just like `cpu_credit` is automatically populated to `standard` by the remote API is not able to detect drift.
There is another attribute called `disable_api_termination` which is also automatically populated to `false` but when I change it from the console to `true`, terraform is able to detect drift there and changes back it to `false`.
So, it looks like a bug to me:(

Comment: I bumped into this while trying to figure out why my `credit_specification` isn't taking at all -- my configuration explicitly says `standard` but it always creates my `t4g.medium` as `unlimited`.  Something is really broke with `credit_specification` at this point...

Comment: If you've found a bug in the AWS provider's handling of `credit_specification` then I'd suggest reporting it in [the AWS provider repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws).